# Customize dynamic fields in DevExtreme with Angular

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am newbie on angular and devextreme. 
I customize fields dynamically as an array, All fields are property of object model. But in `HTML` part I cannot take the values from form to the `datafields`.

```
<*ngFor="let obj of modelUser; let i = index"> 

and datafields are like this :  

<[dataField]="'modelList[' + i + '].id'"
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value being passed is a string (it will try to get a column called 'modedelList[0].id'). Try this:

```
<[dataField]="modelList[i].id"
```